# How to extract some data from POST API response message vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, api

this is my code

```
Private Function POSTData(ByVal json As Object) As Boolean
    Dim url = "***********"
    Dim _httpClient = New HttpClient()
    '_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = New AuthenticationHeaderValue("2022080799", "Emt@9674")
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Username", "****")
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Password", "*****")

    Using content = New StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        Dim result As HttpResponseMessage = _httpClient.PostAsync(url, content).Result
        Debug.Print(json)
        'Debug.Print(content.ToString)
        If result.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created Then
            Console.WriteLine(result.StatusCode)
            Return True
        End If

        Dim returnValue As String = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
        If result.StatusCode <> 200 Then
            Throw New Exception($"Failed to POST data: ({result.StatusCode}): {returnValue}")
        Else
            Debug.Print(returnValue)
        End If

    End Using
```

when I receive the result as follwoing :

**"{""status"":200,""message"":""Operation Done Successfully"",""data"":{""billNumber"":""0007"",""sadadNumber"":""2208800110""}}"**

*how to extract ( "sadadNumber"":""2208800110"" )  ?*

Comment: That looks like a json result you’re getting there,  have a read about deserialisation Json data.

Comment: I added this code:
Dim json2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Container)(returnValue)
                Debug.Print(json2.sadadNumber.SDNo)

But I got this error :
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any idea ?

Comment: I have created the Class:
Public Class Container
    Public sadadNumber As SDAD
End Class

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the better way but it will works :

```
 string asAsked = returnValue.Split(',')[3].Replace("}","")
```

Comment: I tried it but it did not work.